# Backing up user accounts in linux

Tags: linux, backup, archiving, crontab

Following is my steps to backup user accounts with scheduling:

```
`sudo crontab -e.

0 0 * * * sudo tar -cpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1

0 0 * * * sudo tar -cpzf /backupfolder/user2_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user2`
```

Following are my questions:

1. If I do the steps above, did I actually backing up the system configuration files of the users as well when I'm backing up the home directories of the users as shown above?
2. In my crontab command, is it possible that I backup all the users, let's say user1 to user10 in a single line command and append the username or userid to the backup filename automatically? I manage to append date format to my backup filename but not sure whether I can do the same things for the username or not.
3. How can I archive all the user accounts and delete the user accounts?

I appreciate for your guides and suggestions!

Comment: There are a few things outside `/home` that you might wish to backup.  For example a users crontab or mail spool.

Answer (score 0):

> If I do the steps above, did I actually backing up the system configuration files of the users as well when I'm backing up the home directories of the users as shown above?

System and user configuration files are distinct. The only place a regular user account should have any important files is in their respective home directory, or any location under their home directory. Only a few other locations (notably /tmp and friends) outside of a user's home directory are writable by regular users on a normal Linux system. System configuration files are normally kept in /etc, which is not writable by regular users. As pointed out by [Thomas Weinbrenner](https://superuser.com/users/482194/thomas-weinbrenner) in a comment, crontab and mail spool are things that might be kept outside of a user's home directory but still be worth backing up. This depends heavily on what the system is used for, how it is used for those purposes, and how it has been configured.

> In my crontab command, is it possible that I backup all the users, let's say user1 to user10 in a single line command and append the username or userid to the backup filename automatically? I manage to append date format to my backup filename but not sure whether I can do the same things for the username or not.

Make a script that backs up a single home directory the way you want it to (target file naming, compression, encryption, whatever). Let's call that script /usr/local/bin/backup.sh. Make it such that it accepts two parameters: the directory to back up, and a base name for the backup file.

Then call it from a loop:

```
for dir in /home/students/*/; do /usr/local/bin/backup.sh "$dir" $(basename "$dir"); done
```

This assumes that all users have home directories directly under /home/students, but it should be easy to adapt to whatever particular setup you have. The script will end up being called like `backup.sh /home/students/userN/ userN`.

> How can I archive all the user accounts and delete the user accounts?

Delete or archive the files, then remove the user account entries from /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and possibly /etc/group. Use `vipw`, `vipw -s` and `vigr`, respectively, to edit these files with proper locking. Set `$VISUAL` to the command for your favorite editor (for example, `VISUAL="nano -w"`).

Comment: Hi, million thanks for your time to answer my 3 questions. However, I still have some doubts on my question 2 as I merely had some experiences on linux scripting. First of all, is this the line that I have to add in my script file after '#!/bin/bash' ? `for dir in /home/students/*/; do /usr/local/bin/backup.sh "$dir" $(basename "$dir"); done` ? The next thing, how can I integrate my tar command ? Sorry, I'm really confuse and lack on experience. Thank you.